# Cant get ShopifyAPI::Address destroy working

Tags: shopify

I have a piece of code in my controller:

```
customer = ShopifyAPI::Customer.find(custid)
customer.addresses.each do |address|
    if address.id.to_s == params[:addressid]
        address.destroy
    end
end
```

This returns in the log file response code 406

Ive also tried variations on `ShopifyAPI::Address.delete(address.id)` but that doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, answering my own question so other people don't spend hours trying to find an answer. To delete a customer address you need to use activeresource custom methods and do something like below

```
 customer = ShopifyAPI::Customer.find(custid)
 customer.delete("addresses/"+params[:addressid])
```

where params[:addressid] is an address.id you are passing in from a view